# Footer not staying down

Tags: html, css

Alright so i know this is a topic so many people have problems with and i have tried almost every method to keep this footer down the bottom of the website but it just won't stay down. On chrome its working fine, on mobile devices and jsfiddle it won't stay down?

EDIT: Sorry everyone i was meaning i wanted it to stay at the bottom of the page not stuck there when you scroll.

`example:`
https://jsfiddle.net/1dxq8w4L/1/

I am also having another unusual issue. My container is only covering up to the cover and will not expand to cover the content or profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:30px;
    padding-top:15px;
    background-color:#222;
    color:white;
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

specifically, we are making the position set to **fixed**, that way it will always stay there. 
However with this method, anything underneath the footer will be hidden, so to fix that:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    max-width:900px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:orange;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

We are adding margin-bottom:30px; so that there will be a 30px space at the bottom of the page!
JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1dxq8w4L/2/

EDIT:
Based on your comment:
https://jsfiddle.net/1dxq8w4L/4/
should fix your issue.
The container should have
`overflow:hidden` 
because you have floating divs inside of it. This still stop it from overflowing.

Also removed `bottom:0;` from the footer. I moved the footer inside , because generally all page content goes inside the  tags.
Take a look at the code above to see if I missed anything :)

Comment: Sorry i think i made it hard for everyone, what i was trying to say was have it at the bottom of the page. not stuck there when you scroll.

Comment: Would be great if you could make this the accepted answer, haha ;)

Comment: Haha will do in 2 minutes :P

Answer (score 0):

Change *`position`* to `fixed` in your CSS's footer properties. Fixed positioning ensures that the footer will stay at the bottom of the page.

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:30px;
    padding-top:15px;
    background-color:#222;
    color:white;
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response i don't want it fixed at the bottom of the page i would just like it to be at the bottom of the page completely not stuck there while i scroll.

Comment: Sorry i think i made it hard for everyone, what i was trying to say was have it at the bottom of the page. not stuck there when you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the footer fixed in the css instead of absolute. otherwise... when you scroll down it'll go with the scroll instead of stay down the bottom.

something like:

```
position: fixed;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
height:30px;
padding-top:15px;
background-color:#222;
color:white;
```

Comment: Sorry i think i made it hard for everyone, what i was trying to say was have it at the bottom of the page. not stuck there when you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

footer
        {
             min-width: auto;
             background-color: Black;
            color: White;
            clear: both;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 1px;
        }